# Connection management when using kafka producer in high traffic environment

Tags: java, php, message-queue, apache-kafka

I am going to use kafka in a very high traffic environment of more than a billion requests per day. Every request will make a connection to kafka cluster to send message. So there will be so many connections being made continuously every second. This could cause issues like socket timeouts.
producer is making all the non-persistent connections. So in such case there could be socket timeout or port exhaustion issues.

Most ecosystem is in php, so I have to use php library for kafka. Now how to effectively use kafka producer to mitigate this connection contention?

I thought of a daemon process which can be fed messages and it will then send these messages in batch to kafka cluster. Plus side is that there can be limited number of connections. Down side is that response latency of such service will hamper the application. Also I have to use some intermediate storage to hold messages.

Now I know that there are many extremely high volume applications/sites using kafka to directly stream the messages. Can any one of you guide me about how to tackle these issues? Can persistent connections help in this case? Is using php library of kafka-producer in such high volume environment itself is a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also uses kafka java library and we do that like a @apatel says, I think that in your situation you could try to provide some sidecar to your servers with php app, sidecar will create Producer at start and Kafka java driver will manage multiple connections. Here is some interesting article about Netflix's sidecar application [Netflix Prana](http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/prana-sidecar-for-your-netflix-paas.html)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and the link. However, I could not connect how system like prana could be used as kafka-producer. Do you mean to say that only way to implement kafka-producer is to keep it running parallel to main application and have it queue the messages in background? If so, will creating a daemon process will be good?

Comment: Prana is only example to introduce you to sidecar pattern. In this case you should develop you own sidecar, for example: some tiny java application with embedded http server (eg Undertow), app will connect to kafka on startup and provide api to post messages eg: /messages/$topic then your php application will send messages to /localhost/messages/$topic

Comment: of course sidecar should be deployed on the same machine as your php application.

Answer (score 2):

We are using kafka java library, and we connect to kafka on server startup. Currently we're sending about half billion messages to kafka everyday and never had any issue with it.

When you create Producer, it basically create multiple connections... one for each partition. So as long as you're using partitioning, you should be fine sending each message directly to kafka without caching them on your side and sending in batch.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So you are using only one connection object? Also do you send messages directly from within your application or from a separate backend process? If you are using kafka-producer within your web app is it application level object? I mean how do number of established connections stay limited? When I used php's kafka lib, as php has shared nothing arch, as many connections are opened as there are requests, jst limited by server settings. That's a very big thing of concern.

Comment: does producer will send message to newly created partition, which created after connection?